# Click on map pin for detail view gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, exc-bad-access

I have implemented `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` like this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    NSLog(@"calloutAccessoryControlTapped: annotation = %@", view.annotation.title);
    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(mapView:didClickPinButton:)])
    {
        NSString *titleStr =  [(DisplayMap *)view.annotation title];
        [_delegate performSelector:@selector(mapView:didClickPinButton:)withObject:titleStr];
    }
}
```

When I click on pin's button, it goes to method `mapView:didClickPinButton` on main view controller and shows an error:

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1,address=0x......)

This is the `mapView:didClickPinButton:` method:

```
- (void) mapView: (MapView *) mapView didClickPinButton:(NSString *) title
{
    NSLog(@"bsn name-->%@",title);
    for(int i=0;i<[self.categoryListArray count];i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *couponDetail = [self.categoryListArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if([[couponDetail objectForKey:@"category_name"] isEqualToString:title])
        {
            NSNumber *coupon_type=[couponDetail objectForKey:@"coupon_type"];
            int c_type = [coupon_type intValue];
            if(c_type == 1)
            {
                [self callServiceForCouponTypeOneBlock:[couponDetail objectForKey:@"id"] ];
                break;
            }
            else if(c_type == 2)
            {
                BusinessViewController *businessVC = [[BusinessViewController       alloc]initWithNibName:@"BusinessViewController" bundle:nil];
                [businessVC setCouponListDetail:couponDetail];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:businessVC animated:YES];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
[_delegate performSelector:@selector(mapView:didClickPinButton:)withObject:titleStr];
```

The `performSelector:withObject:` method can only be used to call methods that have ***one*** object argument but your `mapView:didClickPinButton:` method has ***two*** object arguments.

You *could* instead use `performSelector:withObject:withObject:` which lets you call a method with two object arguments like this:

```
[_delegate performSelector:@selector(mapView:didClickPinButton:) 
    withObject:mapView withObject:titleStr];
```

However, using `performSelector` here doesn't seem to be really necessary.

It's much easier and simpler to just call the method directly on the delegate so it won't matter how many arguments the method has:

```
[_delegate mapView:mapView didClickPinButton:titleStr];
```